# Dealing with Dual TypeScript installs

Tags: windows, visual-studio, typescript

I'm trying to do some TypeScript tutorials but I'm hitting a weird problem.  A while back I installed TypeScript 1.0.3.0 through Visual Studio here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript

On the command line, when I check the TypeScript version it references that.  I wanted to do some Angular (Angular version 2/4) so I loaded Node Package Manager and installed TypeScript through NPM.  NPM loaded a newer version of TypeScript in another place on my computer.  When I create Angular projects using Angular's CLI tool it somehow uses the NPM install.  When I want to do simple, bare-bones TypeScript tutorials it uses the older version 1.0.3.0.

I lost my MSDN license so I can't run Visual Studio anymore.  How do I update TypeScript that is in the Microsoft SDKs folder?  Every Web site I check on installing or updating TypeScript tells me to use NPM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't plan to use it uninstall it, if you check Window uninstall software console panel page, you should find an item relating to that install.

If it's not there the simplest way would be to remove the old Typescript folder from your path variable (see [here](https://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=%23&ved=0ahUKEwjj2cn1_ITZAhUGLlAKHVPODX4QwqsBCHIwDQ&usg=AOvVaw0VTJzWxrN8ZFOD4xbU2nov) how to edit if you are not familiar). Look for the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript` folder and just remove it.

Then install the latest Typescript from npm.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I checked the Uninstall Programs list and couldn't find it.  I checked my environment variables and saw this:
User variables:
`PATH - C:\Users\SomeGuy\AppData\Roaming\npm`

System variables:
`Path - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;`

So the NPM TypeScript is in the user variables but the old Microsoft one is in the system variables.  Should I delete the TypeScript line from the system variables?

Comment: @user1592980 Yes delete the old version from the system variable

Comment: Thanks!  It's working great now.  I'm on TypeScript 2.7.1.